# How to get count of categorical variable in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, count

| name | grade |
| --- | --- |
| chandler | A |
| joey | B |
| phoebe | B |
| monica | C |
| ross | A |
| rachel | B |
| mike | C |
| gunther | A |

I want to get the count (or frequency) of the grade, which I can get by this:

```
gb = data.groupby('grade').apply(len)
```

But output would be:

```
A 3
B 3
C 2
```

And I want output like:

```
A 3
B 3
C 2
D 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try chain that with `reindex`. Also, use `value_counts` instead of `groupby().apply()` for faster run time

```
data['grade'].value_counts().reindex(['A','B','C','D'], fill_value=0)
```